# How to blur image using CALayer

Tags: ios, core-animation, quartz-core

The following method attempts to apply gausian blur to an image. However it isn't doing anything.  Can you please tell me what is wrong, and if you also know the reason why it's wrong, that would also help. I am trying to learn about CALayers and quartzcore.

Thanks

```
-(void)updateFavoriteRecipeImage{

    [self.favoriteRecipeImage setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.profileVCModel.favoriteRecipeImageUrl] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"miNoImage"]];

    //Set content mode
    [self.favoriteRecipeImage setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
    self.favoriteRecipeImage.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

    //Blur the image
    CALayer *blurLayer = [CALayer layer];
    CIFilter *blur = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIGaussianBlur"];
    [blur setDefaults];
    blurLayer.backgroundFilters = [NSArray arrayWithObject:blur];
    [self.favoriteRecipeImage.layer addSublayer:blurLayer];


    [self.favoriteRecipeImage setAlpha:0];

    //Show image using fade
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.3 animations:^{

        //Load alpha
        [self.favoriteRecipeImage setAlpha:1];
        [self.favoriteRecipeImageMask setFrame:self.favoriteRecipeImage.frame];
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [documentation of the `backgroundFilters` property](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004500-CH1-SW7) says this:

> #### Special Considerations
>
> This property is not supported on layers in iOS.

As of iOS 6.1, there is no public API for applying live filters to layers on iOS.  You can write code to draw the underlying layers to a `CGImage` and then apply filters to that image and set it as your layer's background, but doing so is somewhat complex and isn't “live” (it doesn't update automatically if the underlying layers change).

Comment: Like Rob said, the best alternative is to render the layers you want to blur to a `CGImage` and then apply the core image blur filter to that.

Comment: @waf [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) currently has 125 different filters, including `GPUImageFastBlurFilter` which is a hardware accelerated gaussian blur.

Comment: What about using `filters` property instead of `backgroundFilters` ? There is not any note in the documentation about it not being available on iOS. Yet, it still has no visible effect. Anybody knows why?

Comment: @drasto [The documentation says the property is not supported on iOS.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CALayer/filters)

Comment: @robmayoff Right, somehow I missed it. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

Try something like below :

```
CIImage *inputImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"test.png"]] ;

CIFilter *blurFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIGaussianBlur"] ;

[blurFilter setDefaults] ;

[blurFilter setValue:inputImage forKey:@"inputImage"] ;

[blurFilter setValue: [NSNumber numberWithFloat:10.0f] forKey:@"inputRadius"];

CIImage *outputImage = [blurFilter valueForKey: @"outputImage"];

CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];

self.bluredImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[context createCGImage:outputImage fromRect:outputImage.extent]];
```